# Как грамотно сохранить cookie в sqlite3 через selenium?

Tags: python, sqlite, selenium

Как можно сохранить cookies определенного сайта в sqlite3 через selenium так, чтобы потом можно было достать эти cookies из бд и передать их обратно на сайт?